# JPA Empty Not to Update Annotation

Tags: string, jpa, annotations

I have an entity object, called User, which represents the application user with typical user information, including password.
I've provided the edit option for every user information, by that user can edit and update his information.
One of the edit fields is password, but I keep it empty field, that only user can enter his new password and can not see his/her current password. I want to provide user the option to not enter his/her password when he/she does not want to change it.
Unfortunately Hibernate update the user object with an empty string as his password, when he kept the password field empty.
I'm looking for a JPA annotation, by that I say to Hibernate do not update password field when it's null or empty.

Does anyone know a possible way?

Best

Comment: Is this a web application? If so, what framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to display the user's password on the page. Fine. But the solution is not to remove the password from the User object! That doesn't make any sense in terms of the domain model; it's pushing a user interface requirement too far back.

Instead, you should let the password be loaded normally, and just not display it on the page. You will then need to write a little custom logic between the page and the User object which handles password updates.

Answer (score 0):

- Define entity listener for your class to implement callback events by `@EntityListeners`, then you can check for null/empty string etc in `@PreUpdate` method.
- Implement `Cloneable` interface & user updates the cloned object, then if needed can apply only the required changes back to original entity & persist it. In this way the previous fields(password) will remain unaffected.
- Can have a transient field with `@Transient` for the password as it isn't retrieved or persisted in database, can be used for edit page. If its changed, copy it to the persistent field, else will not affect database as its transient.